# import SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, sdk

I just finished an application for Android and I would like to put ads on it to earn some money... I decided to use the network Unity Ads but I have a problem : I do not know how to import the SDK library project in Android Studio (this is only explained for Eclipse and I work on Android Studio). Could you explain me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Applifier/unity-ads/wiki/Integration-Guide-for-Android), the SDK seems to be an Eclipse Project :

> To import the SDK library project, go to Eclipse's 'File' > 'Import' menu, and select 'General' / 'Existing Projects into Workspace'

In Android Studio, you just need to go to `File -> Import Project`, then choose the root of your SDK folder, and follow the wizard. All should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 
Go to File-> Import Module. Specify the location and import the module.
Once done; Open Project Structure( You will find a Folder icon at the top) ->Select the app module ->Switch to Dependencies Tab-> Click on + icon to add a Library/File/Module dependency-> There you will find the module you just imported. Add and rebuild.

Comment: at a time, they ask me : "this project refers to Eclipse workspace relative path in its project metadata. To help import the project, please point to an Eclipse workspace directory." What should I answer ?

Comment: @Nachding It seems to me that you're importing an project(or library) that is build in eclipse into Android studio. For this; first just import the existing library into studio as project and build the project. Once successfully build; import this module in your project. Hope that will work